# Прямая речь. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Как будут правильно расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении после прямой речи?

**В последнем действии, когда Правдин говорит Митрофанушке: "Пошел-ка служить" — тот покоряется, так как понимает, что это неизбежное зло, от которого он не сможет убежать**

Comment: Есть в этом предложении то, что называют плеаоназмом: две группы слов имеют один и тот же смысл (неизбежное зло и есть такое, от которого невозможно убежать, а корректнее выражаясь, которого невозможно избежать).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После прямой речи ставится запятая, поскольку она была необходима в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора в сложном предложении.
И, безусловно, необходима точка в самом конце.

[Без прямой речи предложение выглядит так:
В последнем действии, когда Правдин говорит Митрофанушке, тот покоряется...]

Правильно:
**В последнем действии, когда Правдин говорит Митрофанушке: "Пошёл-ка служить", тот покоряется, так как понимает, что это неизбежное зло, от которого он не сможет убежать.**
[**§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159)

***Дополнение***

Схема Вашего предложения такова: **А: "П", а.**

Вот классический пример:
*Я только посмотрел на неё, а она отвернулась и, сказавши: "Ступайте за мной, мой паж", пошла к флигелю* (И. Тургенев).

Comment: В этом случае тире не нужно после прямой речи?

Comment: Нет, тире не нужно. Если не совсем понятно, посмотрите: я дополнила ответ.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!